# XML conversion to Json and DeserializeObject issue - InfoPath namespaces?

Tags: c#, json, xml, azure-cosmosdb, infopath

I am looking into loading a large number of InfoPath XML files into Cosmos DB as Json files to test a possible project. But I am struggling with converting the XML files to Json and then loading back into a c# class. I think this is related to the namespace that InfoPath puts into the XML but I'm not sure. I thought at first I should try to remove all the namespace references from the XML but now I'm wondering if I just need to work more on the definition of the class file. To generate the class file I used Visual Studio "paste as Json". I assumed after loading the XML, saving to Json, then using that as the basis for the new class file, I could load right back into the object but when I call DeserializeObject it always ends up null.

Is this because the class file definition needs to be changed or should I instead look to try and clean the XML prior to converting to Json?

Sample XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?mso-infoPathSolution name="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:infopath:myProject:-myXSD-2017-05-05T14-19-13" solutionVersion="1.0.0.2046" productVersion="16.0.0.0" PIVersion="1.0.0.0" href="https://myportal.sharepoint.com/sites/mySite/myProject/Forms/template.xsn"?>
<?mso-application progid="InfoPath.Document" versionProgid="InfoPath.Document.4"?>
<?mso-infoPath-file-attachment-present?>
<my:myFields xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2017-05-05T14:19:13" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:pc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2007/PartnerControls" xmlns:ma="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/metadata/properties/metaAttributes" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2009/WSSList/dataFields" xmlns:q="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2009/WSSList/queryFields" xmlns:dfs="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/dataFormSolution" xmlns:dms="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/documentManagement/types" xmlns:tns="http://microsoft.com/webservices/SharePointPortalServer/UserProfileService" xmlns:s1="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003" xml:lang="en-US">
    <my:Admin>
        <my:Routing_Order>
            <my:Approver-1_Order>1</my:Approver-1_Order>
            <my:Approver-2_Order>5</my:Approver-2_Order>
            <my:Approver-3_Order>4</my:Approver-3_Order>
        </my:Routing_Order>
    </my:Admin>
    <my:Request_Status>Save as Draft</my:Request_Status>
    <my:Request_Type>CAPEX</my:Request_Type>
</my:myFields>
```

Class file

```
namespace xml_to_json
{

    public class Rootobject
    {
        public MyMyfields mymyFields { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyMyfields
    {
        public string xmlnsmy { get; set; }
        public string xmlnsxsi { get; set; }
        public string xmlnsxhtml { get; set; }
        public string xmlnspc { get; set; }
        public string xmlnsma { get; set; }
        public string xmlnsd { get; set; }
        public string xmlnsq { get; set; }
        public string xmlnsdfs { get; set; }
        public string xmlnsdms { get; set; }
        public string xmlnstns { get; set; }
        public string xmlnss1 { get; set; }
        public string xmlnshttp { get; set; }
        public string xmlnstm { get; set; }
        public string xmlnssoap { get; set; }
        public string xmlnssoapenc { get; set; }
        public string xmlnsmime { get; set; }
        public string xmlnssoap12 { get; set; }
        public string xmlnswsdl { get; set; }
        public string xmlnsxd { get; set; }
        public string xmllang { get; set; }
        public MyAdmin myAdmin { get; set; }
        public string myRequest_Status { get; set; }
        public string myRequest_Type { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyAdmin
    {
        public MyRouting_Order myRouting_Order { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyRouting_Order
    {
        public string myApprover1_Order { get; set; }
        public string myApprover2_Order { get; set; }
        public string myApprover3_Order { get; set; }
    }


}
```

Console test code

```
namespace xml_to_json
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlDocument myDoc = new XmlDocument();
            string sourcedir = @"C:\Users\mystuff\Downloads\test-clean\";
            string xmlfilein = @"test";
            string xmlfile = string.Concat(sourcedir, xmlfilein, ".xml");
            string jsonfileout = string.Concat(sourcedir, xmlfilein, ".json");
            myDoc.Load(xmlfile);
            string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(myDoc.LastChild);
            File.WriteAllText(jsonfileout, jsonText);

            Rootobject obj = new Rootobject();
            obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(jsonText);
            Console.WriteLine(obj.mymyFields.myRequest_Status);   
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not deserialize directly using [`XmlSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx)?  If you use `XmlSerializer` you can completely skip the intermediate JSON representation.

Comment: If I understand your idea correctly, the goal is not to get the XML data into an object. The goal is to get the XML data into a Json format so that it can be loaded into a Cosmos DB and then test using that Json document as an object. The conversion to Json isn't a step I want to skip but part of the process I need to follow.

Comment: OK, then why do you need `Rootobject`?  Once you have `jsonText` you have converted your XML data to JSON format and you are done,right?

Comment: RootObject was created from the paste to Json command I mentioned in my first post. I had hoped Visual Studio could do the translation for me. Having a Json file is part of the step. I could load that the Cosmos DB. However my very next step is going to be reading that file and loading it into an object so I can test creating a UI for these documents. The more I research the more I think I need to remove the namespaces and other directives in the XML before I attempt a conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try code below using xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            XElement routingOrder = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Routing_Order").FirstOrDefault();

            Dictionary<string, string> orders = routingOrder.Elements()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Name.LocalName, y => (string)y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

            string status = (string)doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Request_Status").FirstOrDefault();
            string requestType = (string)doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Request_Type").FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I could do the same with XMLDocument and mapping a path to each node but I was more looking to find a way to get DeserializeObject to work without mapping each node individually. Maybe I will edit the original question to be more focused on how to define the Json object when a namespace is involved.

Comment: Try serializing to a file and then deserialize the file.  This will tell if the class definitions are correct.  Then you will know if the issue is the classes or the json.

Answer (score 0):

Using suggestion from jdweng and XDocument helped to clean the XML file for easier transition to Json. Below is a sample of code I used to clean the document.

```
    XDocument newxdoc = XDocument.Load(xmlfile);
    newxdoc.DescendantNodes().Where(e => e.NodeType.ToString().StartsWith("ProcessingInstruction")).Remove();          
    string newstringdoc = RemoveAllNamespaces(newxdoc.ToString());
    newxdoc = XDocument.Parse(newstringdoc);
```